# How to mute and unmute audio in iPad by tapping a button?

Tags: xcode, button, audio, mute

I'd like to know how to make the mute and unmute the audio on my iPad application by tapping a button. I already have a working code in my viewDidLoad method that plays a music when the app is launched. All I need to do is to create a button that will stop the music from playing and also resume it when tapped again.

Here's my code in my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Bored" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the [AVAudioPlayer API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) - it's all there: play, pause, volume, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I can't seem to make it work. :(

Comment: mmm...looking at the snippet of code you posted, you are not saving a reference to the instance of the `AVAudioPlayer` - so you can't later address it to tell it to play, stop, etc. It needs to be a declared property of your `UIViewController`. Then you can wire it up to IBActions/Buttons in the XCode .nib or storyboard. Loads of tutorials out there - here's one: http://mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/

Comment: @jaytrixz: can this old answer be accepted, assuming it was helpful to your fix at the time?